# Creating a multi-value storing Save System in godot using CFG file system

Tags: save, config, godot, gdscript

I was looking to create a save system in Godot for my game and as I'm not that adept at coding, the only method I could make sense of was writing the data in config files.

The following code is on a Singleton script called `save_system.gd`. It saves and loads the value of one variable array `inventory.inventory_ingredients` as follows -

```
var save_path = "res://Saves/save-file.cfg";
var config= ConfigFile.new()
var load_response = config.load(save_path)

func saveValue(section,key):
    config.set_value(section,key,inventory.inventory_ingredients)
    config.save(save_path)

func loadValue(section,key):
    inventory.inventory_ingredients = config.get_value(section, key, inventory.inventory_ingredients)
```

In the start of my game, I have a "Load Game" button that loads the array as follows -

```
func _on_Load_pressed():
    save_system.loadValue("Inventory", "ingredients")
```

When I trigger the save function, the following script is used -

```
save_system.saveValue("Inventory","ingredients")
```

Everything so far runs perfectly -  like I want it to. But, I would like to expand the number of variables that are saved. To do the same bit of code for every variable separately in every scene in quite a lengthy task and would require huge lines of code. How do I minimize the number of lines, and perhaps a bunch 2-3 variables saved at one go from a node? I would prefer a method that would use the "cfg" method that I have used.

For example, I have a node with 3 variables (x,y,z) that I want to be saved in the following way. Currently, the only method I know to do this is to to do this manually as -

```
save_system.saveValue("Variables","x")
save_system.saveValue("Variables","y")
save_system.saveValue("Variables","z")
```

and a similar method for loading. **I want to avoid this. What do I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Write JSON to a text file

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is well-known standard for serializing data, and Godot provides [standard library functions](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_json.html) to work with JSON.

```
extends Node

func load_save() -> Dictionary:
    var f := File.new()
    f.open("user://save.json", File.READ)
    var result := JSON.parse(f.get_as_text())
    f.close()

    if result.error:
        printerr("Failed to parse save file: ", f.error_string)
    return result.result as Dictionary

func save(data: Dictionary):
    var f := File.new()
    f.open("user://save.json", File.WRITE)
    prints("Saving to", f.get_path_absolute())
    f.store_string(JSON.print(data))
    f.close()

func _ready():
    save({
        "inventory": {
            "ingredients": ["apple", "pear"],
            "items": ["spoon", "fork"]
        },
        "stats": {
            "health": 10,
            "experience": 20,
        }
    })

    print(load_save())
```

We're writing the save file to a [user path](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/io/data_paths.html#user-path-persistent-data), which is a platform-specific location appropriate for application data.
JSON can be used to save arbitrarily complex data as long as it consists of primitive data types supported by JSON (`string`, `number`, `dict`, `array`, `true`, `false`, `null`).

Comment: I have a few queries regarding this code. 1) What does " user://save.json" path mean, how is it different from "res://Saves/"  2) So for every node, I should send the variables I want to save in the form of a dictionary and then pass it through the save function?

Comment: The answer to 1 is in the sentence following the code, try following that link. I'm not clear on what you mean by 2, but chances are you don't want to save every node. I would collect all the information you want to save into one `Dictionary` and write it to a JSON file.

Comment: I didn't realize both were the same thing. Thanks for the clarification for both!